# Why is a click handler not registering on page load using Enquire.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, media-queries, enquire.js

I am trying to have various effects on different breakpoints.

Primarily what I am trying to do is when a category is clicked from the category list **within 720px** the category list should **fade out** and data should be **revealed in that place** but when the width goes **beyond 720px**, the category list **shouldn't fade out** instead **reveal** the data **in another div**.

For now am logging responses in console.

**PROBLEM**

Whenever the page loads in a particular width, click is not performed but once I resize the browser thereon the clicks start registering.

I know the details might not be enough but still..

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "./assets/listcategory.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            $('#content').html(response);
        }
    });



enquire
.register('screen and (max-width: 720px)', {
        match: function() {

            console.log('Width less than 720');

            jQuery('.category').off('click.catSelect');
            jQuery('.category').on('click.catSelect', function() {

                    var category = $(this).data('categories');
                    $.when($('.category').fadeOut(500)).done(function(){
                            //$(this).remove();
                    });
                    console.log('click within 720');

        }
})  
.register('screen and (min-width: 721px)', {
        match: function() { 

            console.log('width greater than 720');

            if($('.category').is(':hidden')) {
                    $.when($('.category').fadeIn(500)).done(function(){
                            //$(this).remove();
                    });
            }

            jQuery('.category').off('click.catSelect');
            jQuery('.category').on('click.catSelect', function() {

                console.log('Click outside 720');
            });

        }

})

});
```

Comment: Why do you post code that is in comments? Please provide [minimal code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Its because the code in comments is the actual I want to use, but for testing purpose I am using them under comments.

Comment: So how is that commented code relevant for your question? If it is relevant, then why is it commented. If it is not, then why did you post it?

Comment: Actually the part which is commented does the main work which I would like to do. But since it wasn't giving me the desired results so I thought of commenting them and just logging the values..

Comment: For now, since it is being deemed not relevant, am editing the question body.

Comment: The elements you want to register the click handler on: are they among the content that is loaded via your ajax call?

Comment: Yes, am trying to register the handler on the category list and this list gets fetched via an ajax call.

Comment: OK, I will prepare an answer...

Comment: Ok. awaiting for it for a looong time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that your `.category` elements have not loaded yet when you call the `register` method, and so `jQuery('.category')` will not match any element, and no event handler is bound.

By the time you resize your browser, the content has been loaded, so that then the elements are found, and handlers are bound successfully.

There are several ways to solve this.

One is to move the calls to `register` into the Ajax success callback, right after you load the html.

Or, you can leave the code where it is, but use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

```
jQuery('#content').off('click.catSelect', '.category');
jQuery('#content').on('click.catSelect', '.category', function() { ... });
```

Note that the `on` and `off` calls are now made on the `#content` selector (could even be `document` if you wanted to), and that the `.category` selector is passed as second argument. This means it will work for `.category` elements that exist now *or in the future*, which is what you need.

Comment: Perfect..Thank you.